# How to Change a CDN Endpoint Origin Type

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-cdn

I have already created and been using a CDN endpoint with origin type of 'Custom origin' that was pointed to an Application Gateway. Now I want to change the origin type to 'Web app' and point to a Function App. I am able to change the `hostName` property to the Function App URL but I cannot find a way to change the origin type and the value continues to be 'Custom origin'. I do not see a property in the ARM template nor any properties in the PowerShell commandlets. Is there a way to change it or do I need to delete and recreate?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to change the `Origin type` manually, when you change the `Origin hostname` to the url of the function app, the `Origin type` will be changed to `Web App` automatically.

Try the powershell command below, it works on my side.

In my sample, the `www-test-com` is the `Origin Name`, it can not be changed once created, so you can just use the old one. If you want to change it, you need to create a new endpoint.

[image]

```
$endpoint = Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/<cdn-name>/endpoints/<endpoint-name>"
$endpoint.Properties.originHostHeader = "joyfun.azurewebsites.net"
$endpoint | Set-AzResource -Force

$origin = Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/<cdn-name>/endpoints/<endpoint-name>/origins/www-test-com"
$origin.Properties.hostName = "joyfun.azurewebsites.net"
$origin | Set-AzResource -Force
```

After running the commands, the result will be like below.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to perform the same update via the portal?